# Csv file reader to organized matplotlib maps

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, csv, organization

Take csv file information, read it, organize into the list to then later take the info and create graphs using matplotlib.

I have tried 6 lists, each with 680 elements. It is very hard to understand how to correlate it to each other list for mapping.

```
with open('movie.csv') as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter =',')

    for row in readCSV:
        movie.append(row[0])
        release.append(row[1])
        distributor.append(row[2])
        genre.append(row[3])
        mpaa.append(row[4])
        tickets.append(row[5])
```

Be able to add up tickets by certain distributors, tickets sold per month (release date) and movies by genre.

How can I do this easier? Or is this the best way? I cannot figure out how to correlate specific indexes, movie[3] makes this much by this dis, now add the total of how much it made to a total for that distributor, then keeping going down the line creating a total for all of the specific distributors?

Answer (score 0):

Just use pandas with [its csv reader](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html?highlight=csv#pandas.read_csv):

`import pandas as pd`

then

`df = pd.read_csv('waka.csv')`

or, to read without headers:

`df = pd.read_csv('waka.csv', header=None)`

After you load the .csv, the DataFrame object will be created. Pandas is incredibly powerful with tables/dataframes and can do nearly everything with it by couple of code lines.

---

Note, that if you are using non-UTF encoding, you should write it in `encoding` parameter:

> encoding : str, optional
>
> Encoding to use for UTF when reading/writing (ex. ‘utf-8’).

For example:

`df = pd.read_csv('waka.csv', header=None, encoding='cp1026')`

Here is the [list of standart encodings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings).

Comment: When i try to do this i come accross an error utf-8

Comment: Please, add data sample to your question. It is hard to understand what is wrong without it.

Comment: What encoding do you use in your file? If not UTF-8, you should add `encoding` parameter to `read_csv`. Edited the answer.